# Trying to store A1-A12 numbers in Array. Runtime error 9

Tags: excel, vba

This is my code. I am trying to store the a list of decimals in cells A1 to A12 into the array a. However I keep getting a runtime error 9.

```
Sub Display()

    Dim s As Integer 'selector inputbox
    
    Dim i As Integer 'counter of row
    'a stores data
    'b stores sorted copy
    Dim a() As Variant
    Dim b(20, 1) As Double
        
    a = Range("a1:a20")
        
    Call Bubble(1, a, b)
    
    Range("a12").Select
    
    'printing b
    For i = 1 To 6
        
            ActiveCell.Value = b(0, i)
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
            Debug.Print b(0, i)
       
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, -5).Select
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Array `b` has size (20,**1**) but in string `ActiveCell.Value = b(0, i)` you try to get elements (0,**i**) where **i=1..6** (out of range)

Comment: Also line `ActiveCell.Offset(1, -5).Select` cause 1004 error because `ActiveCell` after `Range("a12").Select` is `a12`, and `ActiveCell.Offset(1, -5).Select` will select cell `(row 13, col -4)` wich does not exist

Comment: How do I fix these issues

Comment: Make sure you copy the values and not a `Range()` object to the array. Use `a = Range("a1:a20").Value`

Comment: Also, there is no need to _ever_ use `.Select`

Comment: Well if your code is built around `ActiveCell` then you do need `Select` is some cases. Best to avoid coding around `ActiveCell`.  Also it's worth noting that `Select` changes the `ActiveCell` and this makes your code very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

To store the list of decimals in cells A1 to A12 into the array a, the following is enough:

```
Dim a As Variant
a = Range("A1:A12").Value
```

No need to use selection.

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem is the `a = Range("a1:a20")` statement. You need to add the `.Value` qualifier so you transfer the values and not a `Range` object.

All the other issues are addressed below using examples:

---

To store a `n×m` table of data from a range into an array do the following

```
Dim vals() as Variant
vals = Range("A1").Resize(n,m).Value  ' The .Value is important here

' Now iterate through all the values
For i=1 to n
   For j=1 to m
       Debug.Print vals(i,j) 
   Next j
Next i
```

In reverse, you would do

```
Dim vals() as Variant
ReDim vals(1 to n, 1 to m)
For i=1 to n
   For j=1 to m
       vals(i,j)  = ...
   Next j
Next i

Range("A1").Resize(n,m).Value = vals
```

Remember the rule is `vals(i,j)` where `i` is the row number, and `j` the column number. This is compatible with direct access to the cells with `Range("A1").Cells(i,j).Value`

In addition, if your data moves from `A1` to `G7` for example, all you need to do above is change all references to `Range("G7")` and the remaining code is the same. This is unlike the `Range(A1:D12)` type of reference, or the absolute referencing using  `Worksheet.Cells()`.

Final note. The result of a `.Value` operation in a range of cells is *always* a 2D array of `Variant` where elements can be either `Double` or `Long` type. Only if a singular cell is referenced the `.Value` returns just the value and not an array. The array index always starts at `1` for both dimensions.

```
Dim x as Double, a() as Variant, b() as Variant

x = Range("B2").Value
' x = <the value of cell B2>
a = Range("C2").Resize(20,1).Value
' a = Array(1 to 20, 1 to 1)

' But when writing arrays they can be 0 based
ReDim b(5)
Dim i as Long ' Always use Long instead of Integer
For i=0 to 5
  b(i) = 1 + 2*i
Nex i
Range("D2").Resize(1, 6).Value = b
```